# What do Team Rocket do with the Pokémon they caught and use to attack Ash and his friends?

Tags: pokemon, team-rocket

Like Yamask, James' *Best Wishes*-era Pokémon; Pumpkaboo, Jessie's *XY*-era Pokémon; Mareanie, James' *Sun and Moon*-era Pokémon; and the other Pokémon which Team Rocket uses only to attack Ash and his friends.

I know that in *Sun and Moon* they left Mareanie behind, but what about their other Pokémon they use to attack Ash with?

I’m not asking about all the Pokémon Team Rocket catch, I’m only asking about the Pokémon Team Rocket use to attack Ash with.

Comment: How are you drawing the distinction between "the Pokémon Team Rocket catch" and "the Pokémon Team Rocket use to attack Ash"? Given that attacking Ash takes up 90% of their screentime, you'd expect that every Pokémon they catch will end up being used against him eventually, regardless of why it was originally caught.

Comment: I'm assuming they spend at least some time making Magikarp fritters over an open Charizard tail.

Answer (score 5):

- **Lickitung** was accidentally [traded away](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP146) for Wobboffet.
- **Victreebel** was intentionally [traded away](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP261) for a Weepinbell.
- **Arbok (nee Ekans)** and **Weezing (nee Koffing)** were [released](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/AG006) to lead groups of Ekans and Koffing.
- **Chimecho** was [left](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/AG147) with James's grandparents.
- **Cacnea** was [given](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP054) to Gardenia to train.
- **Dustox** was [released](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP073) to be with other Dustox and its mate.
- **Seviper**, **Yanmega**, **Mime Jr**., **Carnivine**, **Gourgeist** (nee **Pumpkaboo**),  and **Inkay** were all left at Team Rocket Headquarters at times prior to going to a region where they'd attract attention (Bulbapedia doesn't cite episodes for these).
- **Woobat**, **Frillish**, **Yamask**, and **Amoongus** were all [given](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/BW142) to Giovanni as their only progress in Unova.
- **Mimikyu** and **Mareanie** were [left](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/SM146) with Bewear in Alola when Jessie and James were headed back to Kanto.

Over the years, Jessie and James have also fought using various Pokémon for very brief stints for a multitude of reasons.  There are simply too many to list here, but Bulbapedia has a [comprehensive list](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_temporarily_owned_by_the_Team_Rocket_trio).